# meaning of the word "over" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/a-fast-cut-to-fat-loss-using-giant-sets.html). Here is the passage:

> Three giant sets comprised of four exercises will therefore provide 12 sets per body part, each muscle grouping targeted from all angles **over** what is technically the same set.

Because of the word "over" I cannot get what the author means. Could you rephrase the second part of the sentence for me please?

Comment: It is certainly a confusing sentence, because the author uses the word **set** twice with different meanings- the first time for somethng that there is three of, and the second time for something that there is twelve of. It's not clear which meaning should be used for the third occurrence of **set**.  My guess is that the meaning of **over** is **during something, or while doing something**.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over. If my interpretation is correct, the best way to rephrase it would be to replace **over** by **during**.

Comment: I interpret "over" here as "covering" or "overlapping".